# how to generate a document for a receipt printer using android

Tags: android

Ok, here we go, I have to develop an application, which has to allow electricty and water bill payment, and naturally it's supposed to generate at the end of the transaction a receipt, I particullary need to know how to transfer data and determine what would be displayed on the reciept.
I'v gone through this forum and i've found out some StarIO android sdk, knowing that I have a weak english, and it's a bit hard for me to figure out what's going on in the starIO's documentation, i would like to know if StarIO's packages' are what I need for this application or I just misunderstood the objective behind it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have to work with a Star printer, then yes, their SDK is the way to go. If not, though, we'd need a lot more details to answer your question fully.

Comment: thanks a lot, I will ask more question about that and then, i will comment again ok? thanks again

Comment: Ok, Today I asked about the mobile printer, and it says: ZEBRA MZ 220 what do you think about???

Comment: Well, there's [this](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/adapt-software/zebralink-sdk-android.html) (please use Google before asking here) but I've never touched anything remotely related to mobile printers, so I can't say if it's any good. It likely is your only option, though.

Comment: thank you, just for the record (I always use google), I just thought that in Stack Overflow, I will find better advises than those of (use google before asking) :)

Comment: This is a really niche vendor-specific question. SO is generally not very good for answering these sorts of questions.